# Unjustified delay on java-8 CompletableFuture callback calls

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, completable-future

First callback call is quite fast and the rest are delayed ~50ms (non additive) and I don't know why.

```
public class CfTest {

    final static long t0 = System.nanoTime();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CompletableFuture<Integer> cf1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->{sleep(2000); return 100;});
        CompletableFuture<Long> cf2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->{sleep(1000); return 1L;});
        CompletableFuture<Long> cfs = cf1.thenCombine(cf2, (a,b)->a+b);
        cfs.thenAccept(x->debug("a1. " + x)); // Async process, sync when complete
        cfs.thenAccept(x->debug("a2. " + x)); // Async process, sync when complete
        cfs.thenAcceptAsync(x->debug("a3. " + x)); // Async process, async after complete too
        debug("b. " + cfs.join()); // Wait and process
        debug("c. " + cfs.join()); // Wait and process
    }

    private static void sleep(int i) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(i);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private static void debug(Object res) {
        System.out.println(String.format("after %.3fs: %s", (System.nanoTime()-t0) / (float)TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1), res));
        System.out.flush();
    }

}
```

output:

```
after 2,067s: a1. 101
after 2,129s: a2. 101
after 2,129s: a3. 101
after 2,129s: b. 101
after 2,129s: c. 101
```

**EDIT: Other cases that surprises me even more. I think CompletableFuture may not be the problem.**

If I add this line:

```
    ...
    cfs.thenAcceptAsync(x->debug("a3. " + x)); // Async process, async after complete too
    System.out.println("Waiting..."); // <-- New Line
    debug("b. " + cfs.join()); // Wait and process
    debug("c. " + cfs.join()); // Wait and process
```

I get this output, no change:

```
Waiting...
after 2,066s: a1. 101
after 2,121s: a2. 101
after 2,122s: a3. 101
after 2,122s: b. 101
after 2,122s: c. 101
```

But if I add this line instead:

```
    ...
    cfs.thenAcceptAsync(x->debug("a3. " + x)); // Async process, async after complete too
    debug("Waiting..."); // <-- New Line
    debug("b. " + cfs.join()); // Wait and process
    debug("c. " + cfs.join()); // Wait and process
```

The delay is gone!!

```
after 0,068s: Waiting...
after 2,066s: a1. 101
after 2,067s: a2. 101
after 2,067s: b. 101
after 2,067s: a3. 101
after 2,068s: c. 101
```

Comment: Another curious thing: If you add more printouts to the beginning of the `debug()` method, e.g. multiple `System.out.format("after %.3fs: %n", (System.nanoTime()-t0) / (float)TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1));`, only the first printout shows the faster time, subsequent ones have the extra delay.

Comment: Also - if you change the `System.out.println` in `debug` to just append to a list of strings you still get the delay.

Comment: I got the answer, nothing to do with concurrency/threads nor even IO, it is class loading. I'll post it.

Comment: It might be due to the string format internally being parsed and cached. If you just your `System.out.println(String.format(... ) )` line multiple times, there will be a delay only between the first and second call.

Comment: `System.out.flush()` is obsolete, `println` implies flushing. Oh, and why do you use `println(String.format(…))` instead of `printf(…)`? Twisted thinking?

Comment: @Holger `println` implies flushing only if the stream's autoflush is enabled and I have never seached if that is the case of `System.out` or not. `printf` is (internally) synchronized but does not ensure the whole line is written to the underlaying stream in one atomic operation, and on the other hand it does not imply newline. I don't like `"%n"` at the end of the format string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I add this line before join the delay is gone, so the delay must be related to class loading about String.format initialization:

```
    ...
    cfs.thenAcceptAsync(x->debug("a3. " + x)); // Async process, async after complete too
    String.format("test"); // <-- Delay is gone with this line too
    debug("b. " + cfs.join()); // Wait and process
    debug("c. " + cfs.join()); // Wait and process
```

output:

```
after 2,057s: a1. 101
after 2,068s: a2. 101
after 2,068s: b. 101
after 2,068s: a3. 101
after 2,069s: c. 101
```

Comment: I'll remember to 'warmup' before tiny benchmarks. Sorry about the missleading question.

Comment: Using the `-verbose:class` confirms this:  
`2.054s: [Loaded java.util.Formattable from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar]
a1. 101
after 2.085s: a2. 101
after 2.086s: a3. 101
after 2.086s: b. 101
after 2.086s: c. 101`